# Data mining to find highest paid employee

Tags: python-3.x

I have a spreadsheet of data that I am using for this code. It has a long list of employees and their base salary and positions. I am trying to find the highest paid person and print out that information. Instead of giving me that, it gives me the last person on the list. It also only gives me the last number of the salary. Instead of printing '209318' it just prints '8'

```
def main():
  my_file = open('IndianaSalaries.csv', 'r')

  list_of_lines = my_file.read().splitlines()

  for i in range(1, len(list_of_lines)):
    one_line = list_of_lines[i]
    line_items = one_line.split(',')
    base_pay = line_items[2]
    highest = max(base_pay)

    first_name = line_items[1]
    last_name = line_items[0]
    university = line_items[3]
    position = line_items[4]

  print("The highest paid person is", first_name, last_name, "with the position of",position,"at",university,"making a base salary of $",highest)

main()
```

Here is example data: Last Name,First Name,Base Pay,University or Office,Position,,,
Aaron, Julia J,97783,Clarion,Chair,,,
Aaron, Paul Neal,23961,Shippensburg,Custodial Worker 1,,,
Aaron, William F,11199,Clarion,Instructor,,,
Abbondanza, Lawrence A. Jr,111099,Edinboro,Instructor, PT Temp,,
Abbott, Ann,107870,West Chester,Chairperson,,,
Abbott, Barbara E.,31687,Edinboro,Fiscal Assistant,,,
Abbott, Kristen Kyle,44795,Clarion,Instructor,,,
Abbott, Mary V,35071,Edinboro,Fiscal Assistant,,,

Comment: `my_file.read().splitlines()` -- don't do that. Instead do `for line in one_line: [your loop]` Python can iterate over  a file the same as a list.

Comment: Also: Add example data. Don't make people make it up for you.

Comment: Its a school assignment and I am required to use `my_file.read().splitlines()`

Answer (score 0):

You are basically just iterating through the data. You are not actually finding the row that has the highest salay.

There are many ways you can solve this. What you can do is have two variables, one to store the max salary (call it, for example, `max_pay`), and another to store which employee (or row) has that max salary (`row_max`).

What you can do is:

1. Initialize max_pay to be a very low number, say 0,
2. In you for loop, check if the `max_pay` is lower than the row's base pay. If yes, then you have found a row (or employee) that has a higher pay, and store that row number in `row_max`. If not, the move on to the next iteration.
3. After the loop, simply print out the row (or employee) whose row number is in the `row_max`

Comment: How do I check the row? I'm a little confused on how I would go about that

Comment: something like this?  `for i in range(1, len(list_of_lines)):
    one_line = list_of_lines[i]
    line_items = one_line.split(',')
    base_pay = line_items[2]
    highest = max(base_pay)
    max_pay = 0
    if max_pay < base_pay:
        max_row = base_pay
    else:
        continue`